# Spelling error in the new Developer Story

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

When I have an incomplete profile in my Developer Story, my job matches are put on hold until all the relevant details are included. A box is shown in the right sidebar to inform me of this, and of what information I still need to include. The last section of it has a spelling error:

> responsabilities

should be

> responsibilities

[image]

Comment: Whatever happened to Rasponsible Dasclosure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharp eyes there :)

Thanks for reporting - fixed and with you in the next build.